# Fragment setCustomAnimations() not working well?

Tags: android, animation, transactions, fragment

I have some problem with using `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_down, R.animator.slide_out_down)`, when I hope two fragment slide down smoothly, the `in-fragment` appears immediately after the `out-fragment` finish the animator of `slide_out_down` , and when I change the animator hoping two fragment slide up smoothly, the `in-fragment` disappears immediately before the `out-fragment` start animator.

look like this picture
[image]

why ? How to solve this ?

---

There are more details.

I have a listview with three items on screen left, and three fragments on right,one fragment for one item.

Sample like

[image]

in `MyActivity`, I  initialize all my fragment in `onCreate()`

```
private void createFragment(int initPosition) {
     mFragment[0] = new Fragment();
     mFragment[1] = new Fragment();
     mFragment[2] = new Fragment();

     mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_layout, mFragment[initPosition]);
     mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

and I set a `onItemSelectedListener` to listview, when listview change it's selection, called `replaceFragment(int fromPos, int toPos)`.

```
private void replaceFragment(int fromPos, int toPos) {
    if(fromPos != toPos) {
        mFragmentTransactoin = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //add animator
        if (fromPos < toPos) {
            mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_up, R.animator.slide_out_up);
        } else {
            mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_down, R.animator.slide_out_down);
        }

        if (!mFragments[toPos].isAdded()) {
            mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_layout, mFragments[toPos]);
        }
        mFragmentTransaction.show(mFragments[toPos]);
        mFragmentTransaction.hide(mFragments[toPos]);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Why not use `replace()`, because `replace()` cause `out-fragment` destroyed, `in-fragment` will initialize every time. It's bad.`show()` and `hide()` could avoid that.

---

animator code :

```
slide_in_up.xml

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="1280"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="translationY"
    android:duration="800"/>


slide_out_up.xml

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-1280"
    android:propertyName="translationY"
    android:duration="800"/>


slide_in_down.xml

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="-1280"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:propertyName="translationY"
    android:duration="800"/>


slide_out_down.xml

<objectAnimator
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1280"
    android:propertyName="translationY"
    android:duration="800"/>
```

---

Any reply is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
mFragmentTransaction.hide(mFragments[toPos]);
//need change to  
mFragmentTransaction.hide(mFragments[fromPos]);
```